# Передача контекста между обработчиками событий в Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Есть Обработчик1, который вызывает форму с полем ввода и кнопочкой применить.
в этом обработчике я могу обратиться к this._id и получить текущий ИД записи, относительно, которой я кликнул.
Далее идет Обработчик2, который содержит обработку нажатия на кнопочку в форме, которая была вызвана в Обработчик1. Когда происходит нажатие, я хочу сделать апдейт по БД для текущей записи, но проблема в том, что в Обработчике2 this._id = undefined. То есть получается, что теряется контекст выполнения.
Или я что то делаю не так)

```
Template.myTemp.events({
 'click .forma': function() { 
    console.log(this._id); //работает 
 }, 
 'click .update-task': function() { 
    console.log(this._id); //undefined 
 } 
});
```

Как передать контекст из события .forma в событие .update-task

Comment: передать ссылку на курсор можно же в параметре

Comment: как параметр функции обработчика2?

Comment: да можно так а так же любым другим способом доступным в js

Comment: Не совсем понятно оказалось, как передать, ибо после обращения данный параметр Обработчику2 не известен. Если сделать переменные в Обработчик1 глобальными и в них внести текущий контекст, то ругаться перестает, но возникает ошибка getCont.bind is not a function. Не понимает попытки указать ему явный контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если события происходят по очереди, (сначала кликнули по `.forma`, потом по `.update-task`), то можно сделать как-то так:

```
Template.myTemp.events({
 'click .forma': function() { 
    Session.set("selected_id", this._id);
    console.log(this._id);
 }, 
 'click .update-task': function() { 
    var selected_id = Session.get("selected_id");
    console.log(selected_id);
 } 
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Данный вариант работает. Может еще кто подскажет вариант с принудительной передачей контекста? а то вроде для js эта тема базовая, но все примеры, которые описаны в доках не срабатывают в моем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Хранить в сессии - не самая лучшая идея.

Почитайте тут [meteorChef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/)

```
Template.myTemp.onCreated(function(){
       this.selId = new ReactiveVar('');
    });

Template.myTemp.events({
    'click .forma': function(e,t) {        
       t.selId.set(this._id);  
       //Session.set("selected_id", this._id);
        console.log(this._id);
     }, 
     'click .update-task': function(e,t) { 

        //var selected_id = Session.get("selected_id");
        console.log(t.selId.get());
     } 
    });
```

Comment: спасибо за ссылку и пример. Все работает как нужно)